# Splitting Strings in JS

Tags: javascript

I know how to split strings in Python using square brackets ( `[3:]` ) / whatever number you want, but I cannot find how to do that in JS. Nothing seems to match what I am looking for. I am not very experienced in JS so I apologise if this has a very obvious answer.

Comment: Have you made a Google search before you asked it?

Comment: note that the term you're looking for is actually string _slicing_, not string _splitting_

Comment: Maybe [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @offstagealmond could you please clarify if you need to split on a character or if you are trying to get a specific segment of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `substring()` (read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

For example,

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
```

would be equivalent to this Python code:

```
str = "Hello world!"
res = str[1:4]
```

`res` would be 'ell'. The start and end indices work the same as in Python (includes the start index, goes through but not including the end index.

Comment: That's not the answer. JS has a string function, you don't need to do that. Negative vote

Comment: I didn't say that this is the only way to do it, but it's a pretty straightforward conversion of the way Python splits strings on indices, since that's that the user is accustomed to

Comment: isn't the same. Split returns an array, that returns an string.

Comment: the user never said they wanted an array, they said they wanted the equivalent of python indexing (which returns a string)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are several functions in `JavaScript` which can be used to `split` a string.

**1. Split** *- (Split a string into an array of substrings)*

```
var str = "This is a string";
```

```js
var str = "This is a string";
    var res = str.split(" ");
    console.log(res);
```

It is important that `split` gives back an `array` with the string chunks.

**2. Substr** *- (Extract parts of a string)*

```js
    var str = "This is a string";
    var res = str.substr(1, 4);
    console.log(res);
```

**3. Substring** *- (Extract characters from a string)*

```js
    var str = "This is a string";
    var res = str.substring(1, 4);
    console.log(res);
```

**Reference**

[W3Schools Split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
[W3Schools Substr](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)
[W3Schools Substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it: `"STRING,STRING".split(',')`; if you wanted to split the string by commas. Hope this helps

Comment: or you could slice the string every so often. .slice(0,2) if you wanted the first 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches, depending on your needs ...

## String.prototype.split() : Split a string with a separator

> The [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

```js
let myString = "abc def";
let myResult = myString.split(" ");
console.log(myResult); // ['abc','def']]
```

---

## RegExp : Split a string into chunks with defined length

If what you need is to split a string into smaller strings with a defined maximum length, you can use something like this :

```js
function split (input, len) {
    return input.match(new RegExp('.{1,'+len+'}(?=(.{'+len+'})+(?!.))|.{1,'+len+'}$', 'g'))
}

let myString= 'abcdefghi'; 
let myResult = split(myString,3)
console.log( myResult ) // ['abc','def','ghi']
```

Comment: Again...js has a split function, you don't need that

Comment: String.prototype.split lets you split a string into chunks with defined length ?

Comment: that's not the objetive of splitting a string

Comment: Depends in wich language... in PHP , you can provide a second argument to **str_split( stringToSplit, splitLength )** to perform a split based on length.  However , Javascript does not support it natively.

Answer (score -2):

Very simple!

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
```